# Embedded jetty for automated tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, jetty

I am trying to use embedded jetty for automated tests of a web service. However, I keep getting an error 404 when I try to access the service.

This is my src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Snafucator</display-name>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>Snafucator</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:snafucator.service.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Snafucator</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I also want my src/test/resources to be on the classpath as they contain setup of DAOs and other components that implement the service. All the beans required by the service are configured in the snafucator.service.xml. This mainly happens through loading several spring context files. These are files from lower layers and the snafucator.context.xml which defines the service binding and implementation:

```
<import resource="classpath*:setup.context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:core.context.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:snafucator.context.xml" />
```

Morever, I need the target/classes on the classpath as it contains the snafucator.context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- enable autowiring by annotations -->
<context:annotation-config />

<wss:binding url="/Snafucator">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#snafucatorWs" />
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
<bean id="snafucatorWs" class="com.snafu.SnafucatorWSImpl" />
```

This is how I start jetty:

```
    server = new Server(iPort);
WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
root.setExtraClasspath("target/classes/,src/test/resources/");
root.setDescriptor("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
root.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");    
root.setWar("src/main/webapp");
root.setContextPath("/");    
root.setServer(server);
root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
server.setHandler(root);

System.out.println("Starting jetty server on port:" + iPort);
server.start();
System.out.println("Jetty server is started!");
```

When I access `"http://localhost:8082"` I see the WEB-INF and META-INF directories, so Jetty is running. When I try `"http://localhost:8082/Snafucator"` I get an error 404 and the command line says "JAX-WS-Servlet Initialized". When I access any other url under `"http://localhost:8082"` I get a slightly differently formatted 404. So I assume some WS-handling happens.
I am also developing a web application that the service is designed to be a part of. When I include the snafucator.context.xml into that application's context and start the application using the jetty eclipse plugin then everything works fine. But for automated tests I need to start the service standalone.

By the way, I am using Jetty 7.6.14.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure that root.setWar() works in this case. If you are interesed I can post my embeded Jetty way without WAR taht works perfectly for tests and use spring.

Comment: Hi JosefN, I have seen this use of setWar in various places like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718221/add-resources-to-jetty-programmatically or here https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/12/embedded-integration-testing-of-web-applications.html where setWar is called by the constructor of the WebAppContext. But I don't care how it works as long as it works :-) So if you have a running example I would be glad to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me. I think it is not exactly what I was looking for. In particular, I want to start from an existing web.xml. Thanks anyhow. However, I have found a solution that works in my case:

```
  @Override
  public void start() throws Exception {
    // Set up the handler for the web application context.
    WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
    root.setExtraClasspath(extraClassPath);
    root.setDescriptor(new File(appDir, "WEB-INF/web.xml").getAbsolutePath());
    root.setWar(new File(appDir).getAbsolutePath());
    root.setContextPath(contextPath);
    root.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    server.setHandler(root);
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Jetty server is started!");
  }
```

I think the only that changed is that I don't set the resourceBase. This works great now.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

sorry for delay. I use embedded jetty without WAR. Below is simple wrapper for Jetty. You can start it manually in test by start of the context or using

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "path/testContext.xml" })
```

the wrapper class

```
public class JettyWrapper extends Server implements ApplicationContextAware {
        private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Override
protected void doStart() throws Exception {

    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    final GenericWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = new GenericWebApplicationContext();
    webApplicationContext.setServletContext(context.getServletContext());
    webApplicationContext.setParent(appContext);
    context.getServletContext().setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, webApplicationContext);
    webApplicationContext.refresh();
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    dispatcherServlet.setContextConfigLocation("classpath:servlet-context.xml");
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(dispatcherServlet), "/*");
    context.setContextPath("/");
    setHandler(context);
    super.doStart();
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.appContext = applicationContext;
}
```

in context:

```
<bean id="webServer" class="package.JettyWrapper"
    destroy-method="stop" init-method="start">
    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="port" value="${jetty-port}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
```

hope it helps